# SQL Join for multiple tables

Tags: sql, database-design, left-join, inner-join

**Class**

- ClassId (PK)
- ClassName
- ClassCapacity

**Batch**

- BatchId (PK)
- BatchName
- Size
- Status {NotStarted, Enrolled, Completed}

**BatchClass**

- BatchClassId (PK)
- BatchId (FK)
- ClassId (FK)
- NoOfStudents

**Relationship**

- A class has maximum capacity, therefore a batch can have many classes, but at a given time a class can be allocated only for one batch that status is = Enrolled (This is to be validated from the application end)

I want to get all the classes that are **not currently allocated** to a batch that status is not equal to **Enrolled**

This is what I tried,

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Class C 
LEFT JOIN (
    Batch B 
      INNER JOIN BatchClass BC 
        ON B.BatchId = BC.BatchId
    ) ON C.ClassId = BC.ClassId 
WHERE B.Status <> "Enrolled";
```

Even though when I try WHERE B.Status = "Enrolled" it gives all the classes that have a enrolled batch. What I want is the Opposite which didn't work for me from above SQL.

I'm not sure is it something wrong in my design or SQL statement. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There're 2 "not" - "not currently" & "not equal to". I guess you meant "get all the classes that are NOT currently allocated to a batch that status is equal to Enrolled".

Comment: @Teddy to be exact yes. Classes that are currently enrolled should be exempt from all the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This should work fine:</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.* 
FROM Class AS C 
INNER JOIN BatchClass AS BC ON C.ClassID = BC.ClassID
INNER JOIN Batch      AS B  ON B.BatchId = BC.BatchId 
WHERE B.Status <> 'Enrolled';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/579ca/2)

---

### Update 1

Try this instead:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Class AS C 
WHERE c.ClassID NOT IN(SELECT bc.ClassID
                       FROM BatchClass bc
                       INNER JOIN Batch b ON B.BatchId = BC.BatchId
                       WHERE b.status = 'Enrolled');
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df05/22)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt reply and demo. But in the example class 2 should not return as a result. I slightly edited the demo to illustrate my problem more specifically. Check this out [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df05/1/0)

In this Class 4 and 2 both should not return. Because class 2 is tied up with a batch that is currently enrolled and class 4 is not allocated to a batch at all. Hope that clarify the problem. Cheers !

Comment: Great. I just figured that out too. But I marked yours as correct since your answers were helping out a lot from the beginning. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Randy - You are welcome any time :) Its al right, Doesn't matter who got accepted :) Glad I could help. That what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot every one. I figured out a way around for this. Great thanks for Mohmoud Gamal. The demo was helping a lot.

Here is the solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.* 
FROM Class AS C
WHERE C.ClassId NOT IN
(SELECT BC.ClassId FROM BatchClass AS BC 
INNER JOIN Batch AS B ON  B.BatchId = BC.BatchId 
WHERE B.Status = 'Enrolled');
```

In this way it returns all the classes that are currently not allocated to a enrolled batch. [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2df05/9/0) illustrate this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your result miss classes that are not associated with any batch.

```
SELECT C.* FROM Class C 
LEFT JOIN (    
    Batch B
    INNER JOIN BatchClass BC 
    ON B.BatchId = BC.BatchId
) ON C.ClassId = BC.ClassId
WHERE B.Status <> "Enrolled" OR
      B.Status is null;
```